# Getting exception message as : " I/O exceptiot" while working with Interent Explorer driver in webdriver

Tags: selenium

When i am using Internet Explorer driver, in Web driver after doing all the settings (means Path, Zoom-level and Proxy)  i am getting a message in Eclipse Console as :-

> Started Internet Explorer Driver server (64-bit) 2.39.0.0 Listening on port 47966 Mar 05, 2014 8:48:11 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector try Execute INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond Mar 05, 2014 8:48:11 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute INFO: Retrying request

Comment: The exception you posted seems prettly clear what the problem is: `The target server failed to respond`.  Sounds like an administration/configuration problem, and not a coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

These messages are informational only. You're seeing them as the Java language bindings poll for the HTTP server started by IEDriverServer.exe to be fully initialized and accepting requests. You can find more information in several places on the web, including [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/12/seeing-info-messages-in-log-does-not.html).